# When to use colorWithWhite:alpha: vs colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Tags: ios, uikit

When are the appropriate contexts to use each of the Apis?

As in is it better to instantiate a color with grayscale when doing xyz versus rgb values.

Answer (score 3):

*Most* apps that I've worked on use the colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha API, rather than the colorWithWhite.

Having said that, the colorWithWhite would be well suited to a gray-scale based color picker. The first parameter is a grayscale value to be applied to the color, i.e. 0.0 is black, 1.0 is white and values in between are the grays. Or if you want something to be 80% black, you could just:

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f]
```

There are more convenience apis in [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html) such as using hue/saturation as well.